# How to use html meta to verify users site?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am trying to create a wordpress plugin in which user can submit their site and verify ownership via html meta tag. I have no idea how html meta works and also how to verify them via php. I am good at php and i just need some hint how to do this and i will figure it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use html dom to scrape their web page and then just check if they added that particular meta tag.

You can use this -> http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks a lot i will use this but isn't it will be too server intensive if user have large page and the php try to get each and every line. By the way i am using this but is there is any better way ??

Comment: @avinash - Are you expecting to have to verify hundreds of sites every second? Even if this was a very expensive operation, it isn't an operation you will be performing frequently.